# Best solution for scaling section with aspect ratio depending on window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find the best way to scale a whole section (one row) of my layout depending on the windows width maintain the aspect ration. So far I have a css/jquery solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/wittich/yxcf05b0/

**HTML:**

```
<div class='row row1'>Hello world</div>
<div class='row row2 full'>
    <div class='column'><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6f/Earth_Eastern_Hemisphere.jpg/480px-Earth_Eastern_Hemisphere.jpg"
        title="Source: http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view_detail.php?id=2429" /></div>
    <div class='column'>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='row row3'>Hello world</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);  
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size: 14px; }
.row { overflow: hidden; }
.row1 { background-color: #ccc; padding: 50px; }
.row2 { background-color: #ddd; }
.row3 { clear: both; background-color: #eee; padding: 50px; }
.column { width: 50%; float: left; }
.column img { width: 100%; display: block; } 
h1 { font-size: 22px; margin: 25px 25px 5px; }
p { margin: 0 25px 25px; }
.full-wrap { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

**JS:**

```
( function( $ ) {
    var TEST = window.TEST || {};
    TEST.resize_full_div = function(){
        var $window = $(window);
        $window.on('full resize', function(){
            $('.full').each(function(){
                var WinWidth = window.innerWidth;
                var StdWidth = 650;
                var FullDiv = $('.full')
                if ( !$('.full-wrap').length ) {
                    FullDiv.wrap( "<div class='full-wrap'></div>" );
                }
                FullDivScale = WinWidth/StdWidth
                FullDiv.css({
                    'width': StdWidth,
                    'transform-origin': 'top left',
                    'transform': 'scale(' + FullDivScale + ')'
                });
                var FullDivWidth = FullDiv.width();
                var FullDivHeight = FullDiv.height();
                var FullDivFactor = FullDivHeight / FullDivWidth
                $('.full-wrap').css({
                        'width': WinWidth,
                        'height': FullDivHeight * FullDivScale
                    });
            });
        });
    };
    // trigger functions
    TEST.init = function(){
        TEST.resize_full_div();
    };
    $(function(){
        TEST.init();
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    });
    $(window).on('site', function(){
        TEST.init();
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    });
} )( jQuery );
```

[image: example of a layout where the middle section/row will be always scaled with the same aspect ratio]

**I wonder if there is a smarter solution?**

My solution encounter some problems:
HTML
 - other precalculated elements, like slider, moving elements etc., have wrong measurements,
 - If the window width changed because a scale bar was added, the script doesn't correct the calculation

Hope you guys have some helpful advises...

Answer (score 1):

Actually You don't need any script to do it but just by CSS just try to import this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width, initial-scale:1.0">
```

then you can separate columns not using float by using table instead of div:

---

## HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">
            <img src="#url"/>
            </td>
        <td class="right">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Some Text</p>
        </td>
        </tr>
            </table>
```

Then with **CSS** you have to change **any** element which inherits it's width from a parent element, like font-sizes which inherits it's value from `body`.

## CSS

```
table {
    font-size : 1vw;
}
td.left {
    width:50vw;
}
td.right {
    width:50vw;
}
/* This trick might solve other elements problem */
 td > :nth-child(n) {
    width:inherit;
}
```

by this fiddle you can see how it works : https://jsfiddle.net/heartagramir/32b6co7t/

---

## [Tip] Disadvantage of using table

Well as you use table along side vw measurement, you might have some problems fitting the table to body since table uses some border with pixel sizes, it causes a mess.

Comment: I was thinking about a solution like that, but then I have the problem that I have to calculate the percent for each element and tag in the section. In my example its pretty easy 'cuz it concern only the `h1` and `p` tag...

Comment: @wittich img tag must be inside a div tag?

Comment: the `img` `h1` and `p` is only example. I have much more information in the `<div 'column'></div>`. Like images, text other divs (eg. sliders etc.)... Thats why I came up with the `scale` idea.

Comment: @wittich I got your point and your re-sizer is not working to as you add more paragraph to the right div.
I also updated my answer check if it works?

Comment: Yes it works, it maintains always the same proportions. Of cause in the example there is just a certain height available but that doesn't matter...  what matters is that always the same aspect ratio is maintained. I added example with 3 columns http://jsfiddle.net/wittich/yxcf05b0/7/ As I said the height doesn't matters, my aim is that the whole block looks always the same independent of the width of the window. @Heartagramir I could make it understandable.

Comment: thx for your update. It could be an option but as you see in your example https://jsfiddle.net/heartagramir/32b6co7t/ the text size doesn't get adjusted. There for I had to define a relative size of each element/tag used in the columns. If it is only a header and a paragraph its not a big deal but if there more 100 elements its sucks a little...

Comment: @wittich well you just don't have to worry about texts. texts receive their font-size: xx px/vw/em; value from the body which you defined earlier in CSS. apparently we don't have a lot to change. just the same as img we add a font-size: xx vw; it changes the whole table font-size scale-able. I will show you in the next update soon.